The relation between the cardinality of Bore $\sigma$-algebra and axiom of choice
Under axiom of choice, the cardinality of Borel $\sigma$-algebra $B$ is $\mathfrak{c}$.
In this proof axiom of choice is used three times: To prove

$\omega_1$-times recursion is sufficient,
each $|B_{\alpha}|$ is less than or equal to $\mathfrak{c}$ in recursion steps and
$\aleph_1\times \mathfrak{c}\le \mathfrak{c}$.

Is it known how strong types of axiom of choice we need to prove $|B|=\mathfrak{c}$?  According to this, $\mathsf{DC}$ is not enough.
I am also intersted in opposite implication, that is, what restrictions on $|B|$ (like  $|B|\le\aleph_1\times \mathfrak{c}$) can we get using $\mathsf{DC}$?  I know $\mathsf{AC}_{\omega}$ is enough to show 1.
